# OnDestroy em unity

Tags: unity3d, jogos

Olá, alguém poderia me explicar como funciona o OnDestroy() em unity? Qual sua ação específica. A documentação está bem confusa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim como o próprio nome diz, OnDestroy é uma função que é chamada quando o objeto for destruido, isso pode acontecer quando:

- Ocorrer uma troca de cena (Quando trabalhamos com mais de uma cena no Unity, ao alternar entre elas, o método OnDestroy é chamado, e tudo que estiver dentro dele será executado. Isso acontece porquê quando uma nova cena é chamada, a cena atual e todos os objetos que estão nela são destruidos).
- Quando a função Destroy() for chamada (A Função Destroy() força o objeto a se destruir, e quando isso acontece, a função OnDestroy é executada, e nela você pode colocar o que você quer que aconteça quando o objeto for destruido, por exemplo uma animação).

**Resumindo**

A função OnDestroy é invocada quando o objeto é destruido, e você pode a usar para fazer algo quando isso acontecer.

Exemplo do método OnDestroy() aplicado a um objeto:

```
void OnDestroy()
{
   Debug.Log("Estou sendo destruido!!");
   // Rodar animação ou fazer algo
}
```

**Referências**: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html

Comment: Muito obrigada, ajudou muito!!!